# Why does an HREF consisting of a plain forward slash direct to the homepage?

Tags: html, browser, href

I came across an HTML anchor which reads `<a href="\">Home</a>`.

Normally we put something like `<a href="index.php">Home</a>` but when I click on `<a href="\">Home</a>` I am able to go to the index page on the website.

I can't replicate the behavior on localhost.

Why does `\` direct to the website's homepage, and was it intentional on the developer's part?

Comment: I click on Home but it manage to direct to home page. The slash character is actually able to do that? I can't simulate this case in localhost tho.

Comment: Most browsers will replace the backslash (which Windows uses as its path separator) with a forward slash (the one used in URLs and *nix paths).

Comment: The relative path `/` is the "root" path.  Linking to `/` means to link to `example.com/` (or whatever the domain is).  Depending on how the webserver is set up, this will load `index.php` or `index.html`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat It can't work in localhost, correct?

Comment: @4LeaveCover: It should depending on how your webserver is setup and whether you are using `http://localhost` or `file:///example.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that it is incorrect, and it's almost certainly not intentional. Backslashes (`\`) are [considered unsafe](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) in URLs, and if a backslash is necessary in your URL you would normally have to encode it as `%5C`.

#### Why it works

As [Rocket Hazmat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024749/unusual-way-of-direction-to-home-page#comment67327016_40024749) on your question, most browsers automatically substitute `/` for `\` in URLs.

So the link to `\` is converted to `/`, which requests the root of the current server. The server is probably set up to serve some default file like `index.php` when it receives a request for a directory, and the result is loading the homepage.

#### Why it doesn't work in localhost

I don't know your local http server setup, but chances are it hasn't been configured to serve a specific page (like `index.php`) when it receives a request for a directory. So you are likely just seeing a directory listing of whatever is at the root of the local http server you are running locally.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I believe it was just a poor coding or perhaps shortcut way to code rather than expose the page. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, probably just a mistake or misunderstanding on the coder's part, but web browsers are forgiving enough that it still works in the end. Because Windows uses backslashes for traversing directories, I wouldn't be surprised if a Windows developer absentmindedly typed ```\``` instead of `/` as they were writing that anchor tag.